# anagram in c with runtime error

Tags: c, runtime-error, anagram

Why do I get a runtime error?

Output Format

Print a single integer denoting the number of characters you must delete to make the two strings anagrams of each other.

We consider two strings to be anagrams of each other if the first string's letters can be rearranged to form the second string. In other words, both strings must contain the same exact letters in the same exact frequency

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b){
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2){

char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator

strcpy(result, s1);
strcat(result, s2);
return result;
}

int main(){
char* a = (char *)malloc(512000 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s",a);
char* b = (char *)malloc(512000 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s",b);

int l1 = strlen(a);
int l2 = strlen(b);

if(l1 != l2){
    printf("String lengths do not match, exiting\n");
    exit(1);
}

char * s;
for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++){
    s = concat(a, b);         
 }

qsort(s, l1, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

int range[26]={0};

for(int i=0;i<l1;i++){
    int t = s[i] - 'a';
    range[t]++;
}
int count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<=l1;i++){
    count++;
}


printf("%d\n", count);



free(s);
free(a);
free(b);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Why do I get a runtime error?" - because your program invokes undefined behavior somewhere. A *debugger* is made for finding such problems. Use one. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for advice as well.As written there are numerous issues in this code, some of them blatant memory leaks, some of them appearing to be senseless code. Ex: `qsort` using the stride of `int` across a sequence of `char` is highly questionable. The last for-loop seems completely pointless as well.

Comment: `s` is an array of `char`; `cmpfunc()` compares arrays of `int`.  Trying to sort `s` with `cmpfunc()` is not going to lead to happiness.